# Search and delete from TMemo in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a code, to search and delete from memo lines. but there is a little problem that, for example, memo lines contains 1, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22 etc. when e=1  it removes all lines which contains 1. 
I need to delete only defined search (e=1)

```
  for i := 0 to memo3.lines.count-1 do
  begin
    if (pos(IntToStr(e), Memo3.Lines[i]) > 0) then begin
      Memo3.Lines.Delete(i);  
      Memo3.Lines.Delimiter := '-';
      Memo3.Lines.StrictDelimiter := True;
      t:= Memo3.Lines.DelimitedText;
      Label5.Caption:=t;
    end;
```

[image]

Comment: You need to define more exact conditions. For example, shouild string to delete contain only `1` and nothing more? BTW, your for-loop is not appropriate for deleting lines, because count might change.

Comment: I added image file as example. my code deletes 1,11, 31 when e=1, I want only '1' to be deleted

Comment: So compare `if Memo3.Lines[i] = e`, not with pos

Comment: Thanks bro . You are right. without pos it works well.

Comment: See my answer, the **"One number per line?"** part. The fact **you should count down from the top** still remains. @MBo is almost right, if you turn the Integer e into a string (NumStr in my answer). And **don't repeatedly call IntToStr(e), just call it once** and remember the result (in NumStr), **before the loop**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Checking only for the string

If you only want to find the string in isolation, then you'll have to look if before and after the string are no digits:

```pascal
NumStr := IntToStr(e);
Str := Memo3.Lines[i];
NumPos := Pos(NumStr, Str);
if NumPos > 0 then
begin
  if (NumPos > 1) and IsDigit(Str[NumPos - 1])) or
     (NumPos < Length(Str)) and IsDigit(Str[NumPos + 1])) then
    Continue; // i.e. skip deleting etc.
```

*Alternatively, you try to find spaces, tabs, etc. around the `NumStr` you find and only delete if you find that the number is a single "word" in that string.*

#### One number per line?

Now if your `TMemo` **only contains exactly one single number per line**, then things are much easier, and you don't need `Pos()` at all:

```
NumStr := IntToStr(e);
for i := Memo3.Lines.Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  if NumStr = Memo3.Lines[i] then
  begin
    Memo3.Lines.Delete(i);
    ...
  end;
end;
```

*Note that I didn't repeat the call to `IntToStr()` for each iteration of the loop. I Just did this once and assigned the result of the call to `NumStr`. Function calls take time.*

#### Deleting in a loop

If you want to delete from an indexed list of items, like the `Lines` property of a `TMemo`, then, in order not to skip any lines, always loop backwards, like I do above. Because if you delete line `i`, all lines **after** `i` will **move one index down,** so when you go to line `i+1`, that will be the **second to next line**, not the next line (**because that got index `i`, after the deletion**).

But when you loop backwards, the previous line will be `i-1`, and that index did not change.

***Simple example:***

Original situation:

```
index: text
0:     A
1:     B
2:     C  <-- delete!
3:     D
4:     E
```

After deletion:

```
0:     A
1:     B
2:     D <-- now at index 2, was at index 3
3:     E <-- now at index 3, was at index 4
```

If you delete **C** at index 2, then **D** and **E** go down one index, and now **D** is at index 2. But the upward loop increments `i` to 3, so now you inspect line 3, and ***D*** is never checked. But if you go downward, then `i` becomes 1, and that didn't change index and still contains **B**.

Answer (score 1):

When changing the lines in the memo by deleting you cannot loop from 0 to count - 1 because the index changes everytime you delete a line

This loop will delete all lines that contain the value in `e`

```
for i := Memo3.Lines.Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  if pos(e, Memo3.Lines[i]) > 0 then
  begin
    Memo3.Lines.Delete(i);
  end;
end;
```

I have however no clue what the other lines of code in your sample should do, maybe you can elaborate what you are trying to achieve with that.

**EDIT**
If you want to delete only rows that match the value in `e` then use this loop

```
Value := IntToStr(e);
for i := Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  if Value = Trim(Memo1.Lines[i]) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Delete(i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for you help.  but this code didn't help . e=2 deletes both  12, 22, 2, 32, 25, 23, etc

Comment: You should explain better what should be deleted when `e=2` From your current question it is not clear. It states that all rows containing 1 should be deleted when `e=1`, so the same does not apply when `e=2`?

Comment: @GuidoG: see my answer. If e is, say, '2', he doesn't want to delete strings with '92', '27', '25' or '2456', '321' etc, only those with exact '2' in them (I have no idea what else is in the strings). But Pos('2', 'ABCD32DEF88') > 0, although there, the numbers are 32 and 88, and not 2. So that test alone is not sufficient.

Comment: sir, I want when e=2, it will delete only memo line text which is 2, not 12,22, 23,.. other words

Comment: What are your strings? Do they contain one number per line? In that case, it is very simple: `if Memo3.Lines[i] = Str then Memo3.Lines.Delete ...`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Well I did not understood that from the question. But still we need more info about the possible values in the lines. As you already asked a few times, what is in the strings ? We dont know

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Also, what values can be in `e` ? can it contain `12` for example ?

Comment: Rudy, thanks your help. yes each line contain number. when e=2,  it searches all lines and deletes 2, 22, 24, 4253, 8962 .all lines where contain '2'. in the case of your example it also deletes C, AC, BC, DC, ADCV

Comment: @MamedAliyev Can you please edit your question and tell us exact what lines should be deleted when `e=2` and why ?

Comment: when e=2, only line text which is(equal) '2'.   not lines contains 2 and other digits 
21
2    <-------
23
24

Comment: So if the lines contain one number per line, than the code in the edit of my answer should do the trick. The same goes for the answer of @RudyVelthuis (the One number per line edit)

Comment: thanks friends. I am very thankful to you for your support. I solved it not using pos function. if Memo3.Lines[i] = e ..